# Is there a word for a road or river that runs almost "vertical" in the map?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, geography

Is there an adjective to describe a road or a river whose orientation is nearly north to south (e.g. looks vertical in the map)? An example sentence would be, "*the [word] highway between Foopolis and Barville forms the western border of the State of Ipsumia.*"

Comment: How about *north-south*? *East-west* is also colloquial.

Comment: Yep, "north-south" is pretty much it, at least in the US.

Comment: If a river flows north or south or a road runs south and north (since most roads run both ways) it is in coincident with a line of longitude by definition. It is almost certainly coincident with a line of longitude with fractional numbers of degrees (eg 0 degrees 47.32 minutes) but it is still a line of longitude. Therefore it could be said to be **longitudinal**. A road or river running east-west would be **latitudinal**, However north-south and east-west for roads and north-flowing, south-flowing and so on are much more colloquial and likely to be understood.

Comment: @BoldBen - Make that an answer.

Comment: Are you looking for something a professional cartographer might use in a paper, or someone simply describing the road to a friend in casual conversation?

Answer (score 2):

***due north***, defined by [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/due+north)

> the cardinal compass point that is at 0 or 360 degrees

In your example:

> The road running almost due north from Foopolis to Barville forms the
>   western border of the State of Ipsumia.

This isn't a single word, but it is a commonly used and universally understood way of expressing what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use ***meridian*** in its adjective form though to me it feels a bit odd to directly apply it on *highway*.

> "the ***meridian*** highway between Foopolis and Barville forms the
>   western border of the State of Ipsumia."

The following reworked sentence may be easier to understand:

> "the highway *along the **meridian** line* between Foopolis and Barville forms the western border of the State of Ipsumia."

ODO:

> **[meridian](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meridian)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> [attributive] Relating to or situated at a **meridian**: ‘the meridian
>   moon’
>
> ‘A meridian line is a line used by astronomers, meteorologists and
>   others to measure from.’
>
> ‘The meridian line through the Observatory became the official
>   meridian line of Paris.’
>
> *NOUN* (the adjective definition refers to the noun)
>
> **1** A circle of constant longitude passing through a given place on the earth's surface and the terrestrial poles:
>   ‘the European
>   Broadcasting Area extends from the Atlantic to the meridian 40°E’

Answer (score 0):

If a river flows north or south or a road runs south and north (since most roads run both ways) it is coincident with a line of longitude by definition. It is almost certainly coincident with a line of longitude with fractional numbers of degrees (eg 0 degrees 47.32 minutes) but it is still a line of longitude. Therefore it could be said to be **longitudinal**. A road or river running east-west would be **latitudinal**, However north-south and east-west for roads and north-flowing, south-flowing and so on are much more colloquial and likely to be understood.

Answer (score -1):

A little insecure on this one, but I'll give it a shot; in fact, two:

How about *meridianwise*?
(though I understand this would primarily be used as an adverb.)

Hence, my second suggestion: *polarward*

defined as *moving toward polar regions* by both Oxford and Merriam Webster, which basically applies to anything that appears “vertical” on the map. I don't really see a metaphor (in case that's the reason for the downvote); merely a widened usage of the concept actually connoted.

Comment: The downvote is justified. Nobody uses *meridianwise*, and most people reading this word would have no idea what you were talking about.